# Views and Tags (taxonomy) and Tabs in Drupal

Tags: drupal, view, tabs, taxonomy

It is a Drupal 6 installation and I have a content type that has a few taxonomy vocabularies and all terms are in Tags format.

I would like to create Views to show nodes based on terms, and I would like to have those Views displayed in tabs.

For example, four nodes:

node 1: termA, termB
node 2: termA, termC
node 3: termB termC
node 4: termB, termD

I would like to have a tabs display that have four tabs, named TermA, TermB, TermC, TermD respectively.

When clicking each tab, it will show all nodes that are associated with this term.

eg:

For tab TermA, will display node1, node 2,
For tab TermD, will display node 4 only.

Any suggestion on how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Taxonomy Menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu). It might be an easier solution than doing this using views.